# Add a Timestamp to the End of Filenames with Grunt

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

During my Grunt tasks, add a unique string to the end of my filenames. I have tried **grunt-contrib-copy** and **grunt-filerev**. Neither have been able to do what I need them to...

Currently my LESS files are automatically compiled on 'save' in Sublime Text 3 (so this does not yet occur in my grunt tasks). Then, I open my terminal and run '**grunt**', which concatenates (combines) my JS files. After this is done, then grunt should rename '**dist/css/main.css**' and '**dist/js/main.js**' with a "version" at the end of the filename.

I have tried:

- **grunt-contrib-copy** ('***clean:expired***' deletes the concatenated JS before **grunt-contrib-copy**' can rename the file)
- **grunt-filerev** ('This only worked on the CSS files for some reason, and it inserted the version number BEFORE the '.css'. Not sure why it didn't work on the JS files.')

[Here's my Gruntfile.js](https://github.com/DerekFoulk/nwca-nitrosell/blob/master/Gruntfile.js)

So, to be clear, I am not asking for "code review" I simply need to know how I can incorporate a "rename" process so that when the tasks are complete, I will have 'dist/css/main.css12345 & dist/js/main.js12345' with no 'dist/css/main.css' or 'dist/js/main.js' left in their respective directories.

Thanks in advance for any help!

***UPDATE:*** After experimenting with this, I ended up using [**grunt-contrib-rename**](https://github.com/jasonlam604/grunt-contrib-rename) and it works great! I beleieve the same results can be achieved via [**grunt-contrib-copy**](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy), in fact I know it does the same thing. So either will work. As far as support for regex, not sure if both support it, so may be something else worth looking into before choosing one of these plugins :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `rename:dist` looks like it should do what you want, you just need to move `clean:dist` to be the first task that runs (so it deletes things from the prior build rather than the current build).  The order of tasks is defined by the array on this last line:

```
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint:dev', 'concat:dist', 'less:dist', 'csslint:dist', 'uglify:dist', 'cssmin:dist', 'clean:dist', 'rename:dist']);
```

That said, I'm not sure why you want this behavior.  The more common thing to do is to insert a hash of the file into the filename before the file extension.

The difference between a hash and a timestamp is that the hash value will always be the same so long as the file contents don't change - so if you only change one file, the compiled output for just that file will be different and thus browsers only need to re-downloaded that one file while using cached versions of every other file.

The difference between putting this number before the file extension and after the extension is that a lot of tools (like your IDE) have behavior that changes based on the extension.

For this more standard goal, there are tons of ways to accomplish it but one of the more common is to combine `grunt-filerev` with [`grunt-usemin`](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) which will create properly named files and also update your HTML file(s) to reference these new file names

Comment: This is what I ended up doing after I started playing with it :) Thanks!

Comment: The reason I wanted at the end is because our site is built using a software by the name of NitroSell. They have their servers (which our site is hosted on) configured where the versioning is set as I mentioned above. I ended up running into errors with JS files not being allowed to run in Firefox due to a "MIME Type Error" (AKA Firefox does not allow .js12345 files to execute scripts because it is not a valid filetype). This is curious, because NitroSell's JS files run fine. So yes, I ultimately started inserting my version BEFORE the extension... Thanks again for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand completely what end you want, but if you add a `var timestamp = new Date().getTime();` at the beginning of your *gruntfile* and concatenate to your `dest` param that should do the job.

```
dest: 'dist/js/main.min.js' + timestamp
```

Is it what your looking for?

Comment: This is also what I did. I just used `dest: 'dist/js/main' + date + '.js'` where `var date = '<%= grunt.template.today("yyyymmddHHMM") %>'`